# how to add an id to $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] submit

Tags: php, sql

I am wanting to submit a form using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`however its not picking up the id of the item when the form is being submitted, is there a way to add an id like the following and not have to link to another file...

```
<form action="process.php<?php echo"?id=$productID" ?> " method="post">
```

Surely there is a simple way of doing this.. I have spent alot of time googling and searching forums and nothing is giving me an explanation.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

```
include "../model/functions_updateproducts.php";

function select_productspreparedGETIDt(){


    global $conn;


        $productID = $_GET['id'];
        $nameError = "";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID = :productID";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':productID', $productID);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement->closeCursor();

    foreach($result as $row):

      ?>


            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"  method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" id="productID" name="productID" value="<?php echo $row['productID'] ?>" />
                    <label>Product Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName" name="productName" placeholder="Enter Product Name" value="<?php echo $row['productName'] ?>"  /><span class="error"> <?php echo $nameError;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input type="Number" class="form-control" id="QTY" name="QTY" placeholder="Enter Quantity" value="<?php echo $row['QTY'] ?>" min='1' max='100' >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" placeholder="Enter Price" value="<?php echo $row['productPrice'] ?>" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Variable</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Variable" name="Variable" placeholder="Enter Variable" value="<?php echo $row['Variable'] ?>" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="productDescription"  name="productDescription" /><?php echo $row['productDescription'] ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update Item</button>
            </form>


            <?php

                endforeach;
      }

      $nameError ="";

      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if (empty($_POST["productName"])) {
     $nameError = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["productName"]);
     // check name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
     }
   }

   $productID = $_GET['id'];
   $productName = $_POST['productName'];
   $productDescription = $_POST['productDescription'];
   $productPrice = $_POST['productPrice'];
   $QTY = $_POST['QTY'];
   $Variable = $_POST['Variable'];

     global $conn;

     $sql = "UPDATE product SET productName = :productName, productDescription = :productDescription, productPrice = :productPrice, QTY = :QTY, Variable = :Variable WHERE productID = :productID";
     $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
     $statement->bindValue(':productName', $productName);
     $statement->bindValue(':productDescription', $productDescription);
     $statement->bindValue(':productPrice', $productPrice);
     $statement->bindValue(':productID', $productID);
     $statement->bindValue(':QTY', $QTY);
     $statement->bindValue(':Variable', $Variable);
     $result = $statement->execute();
     $statement->closeCursor();
     header("location: ../view/success.php");
     return $result;

   function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
   }
      ?>

      <?php

}
?>
```

Comment: why do you need to put GET parameter in action? If you want to submit to the current page, then just let `action=""`. Or either way you may pun `$productID` in in hidden input as well. `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$productID" />` .

Comment: just put in the action the name of the file where the form is (this is what SELF does) and add as you are doing all the data you want. or do like Mr hery says and put the id in a hidden field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your form put this code:

```html
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $productID ?>" name="id" />
```

This will submit the hidden field. PHP wrote your `$productID` to it and it get submitted as part of the `$_POST[]`

Comment: Beauty i see the logic in this however i am still getting the issue of it not recognising an id must be missing something else as well.

Comment: are you using `$_POST[]` or `$_GET[]`?

Comment: I will edit my post so you can see where i am at... if your up for it...

Comment: Use the input and change all `$_GET['id']` to `$_POST['id']`

Comment: When i do that it seems to not even load the page that is required to update the information

Comment: Yeh just undefined id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176572/discussion-between-marvin-fischer-and-jack-warren).

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="process.php<?php echo"?id=$productID" ?> " method="post">
```

is totally fine.. access the productID with

```
$_GET['id']
```

Comment: Yup i get that but i am trying to validate the form and i can only seem to find a way to validate the form with php using the PHP_SELF method

Comment: i dont see whats exactly your problem is

Comment: Initial issue it implementing validation with my form using php, however i can only seem to do this using PHP_SELF, however i can't select a ID from my database with PHP_SELF using <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $productID ?>" name="id" /> looks like it should work but i seem to be having an issue somewhere else.